# How to access key-value pair of Cookies in Grails?

Tags: grails, cookies

For Example:

Cookie name is "example" and key-value pairs stored inside this cookie are: { a: "A", b: "B", c: "C"}

In other words:

**Cookie Name:** example
**Cookie Value:** {a: "A", b: "B", c: "C"}

```html
def element=cookie(name:'example')
println element.b
```

Here, **element.b** doesn't work. Ideally I'm expecting the output as: **"B"**

**Is there any way to access key-value pair of cookies?**

I need to access key-value pairs inside a Grails Controller, any alternative way to do this would be appreciated as well!

Comment: Are you try to use cookie plugin?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Grails Cookie Plugin. It provides support for just one value for a given key. I'm looking for advanced solution where a cookie will have multiple key-value pairs stored as a value. jQuery Cookie Plugin seems to have the feature but I need to access the cookie inside controller and hence looking for Grails way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the data in JSON-format as coockie's value. Thus you can always marshall/unmarshall the values back and forth

UPDATE:

more like that:

writing:

```
String result = '{ "person":{"name":"xplore","age":3,"pets":["dog","cat"]} }' 
cookieService.setCookie 'cookie_name', result
```

reading:

```
def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText cookieService.getCookie('cookie_name')
assert 3 == data.person.age
```

Comment: I tried below which doesn't work. Would be useful if you have any input.

Comment: def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('"person":{"name":"xplore","age":3,"pets":["dog","cat"]}')
cookieService.setCookie('cookie_name',result)
def data=cookieService.getCookie('cookie_name')
println "Age:"+data.person.age

Comment: thanks for the detailed solution! added some brackets and it worked like a charm!